# Add numbers from dataframe and convert it into html string R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, html-table, dplyr

I have below mentioned data frame in R:

```
ID          T1     T2       T3        T4      T5     T6
Jul-17      8      2        1000      1       1      15000
Jun-17      3      2        2000      5       1      25000
May-17      9      2        5000      4       1      30000
```

I want to create below mentioned bullet line from above dataframe (by adding `T1` and `T4` for line one and `T3` and `T6` for line 2) and than convert it into html format.

The code should pick the `Jul-17` from first row of dataframe.

- some text here `Jul-17` are **9**.
- some text here `Jul-17` are **25,000**.

I have already two html tables as shown below, where i have some free space remain in top right hand side (mentioned as `Space` in below example) where i want to paste these 2 bullet line when using `mailR` library to e-mail it.

Body looks like below:

```
Table1 Space

Table2 Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be close

```
s = sprintf(
  "some text here <span style='background-color: #999999;'>%s</span> are <b>%s</b><br>some text here <span style='background-color: #999999;'>%s</span> are <b>%s</b>",
  df[1,'ID'],
  df[1,'T1'] + df[1, 'T4'],
  df[1,'ID'],
  formatC(df[2,'T3'] + df[2, 'T6'], format="d", big.mark=",")
  )

cat(s)
```

```html
some text here <span style='background-color: #999999;'>Jul-17</span> are <b>9</b><br>some text here <span style='background-color: #999999;'>Jul-17</span> are <b>27,000</b>
```

Comment: How would i set this in my blank space on top right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate HTML code from R, take a look at the `shiny` package. While shiny is built to make interactive web apps using R, its core is a collection of R functions that generate HTML code in a much more readable way. For example:

```
shiny::tags$ul(
    shiny::tags$li("some text here ",
                   x$date,
                   " are ",
                   x$num)
)
```

Will return:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    some text here 
    Jul-17
     are 
    9
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to generate this programatically you can do that too:

```
lis <- lapply(1:3, function(i) shiny::tags$li("some text here ",
                                              i))
shiny::tags$ul(lis)
```

Returns:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    some text here 
    1
  </li>
  <li>
    some text here 
    2
  </li>
  <li>
    some text here 
    3
  </li>
</ul>
```